# Can a Java Bean contain one or more parameterized constructors?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I have a question. According to my knowledge, Java beans have the following properties.

- They should be serializable, i.e. they should implement the serialization interface.
- They should have a no-argument constructor.

What is the meaning of **have a no-argument constructor**? Does it mean that there can only be a no-argument constructor? Can't they have parameterized constructors? Does that mean that bean classes cannot have constructor overloading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the bean class must have a no-argument constructor. It can have as many constructors as you want, but it must have one no-argument constructor.

Take into account that any java class without defined constructor will have a default no-argument constructor, but if you add any constructor with arguments, you need to explicitly define a no-argument constructor in this case.

Answer (score 2):

A Java Bean *may* have parameterized constructors, but they won't be used for the purposes that the original Java Beans specifications were intended to serve: frameworks that use reflection to instantiate objects.

Java Beans were devised to enable tools like UI designers. By following conventions for constructors and accessors, tools can create and manipulate objects in a consistent manner at "design time", without knowing anything about the particular class involved. The resulting object instance with its configured properties could be reconstructed later at runtime, using generated code or deserialization.

Over time, the Java Beans concept was used in more and more contexts, but most rely on similar conventions: a public, no-arg constructor, and public accessors with special names.

These don't stop you from adding additional constructors and methods, but they won't be usable by most Java-Beans–oriented frameworks. They will be available to your hand-written code though, and that can be quite useful.

For example, a dependency injection framework can use the Java Beans conventions to construct and configure an object that also implements an interface that doesn't follow JavaBeans conventions. You write code ("by hand") that depends on an instance of that interface to do its job. You don't care where the object came from (constructor) or its properties (accessors); you just use the interface methods.